# Image not showing after disposing stream in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, idisposable

I have an `Image` that is shown using `ImageSource.FromStream` method. For that I use **Xamarin.MediaGallery** plugin. Everything works fine and image is shown properly. The problem arises after I call stream's `Close()` or `Dispose()` method. We are required to dispose stream after use, but when I dispose the stream, Image is not shown. Am I required to Dispose this stream? Am I doing it correctly?

Note that Image is shown properly if I add 3000ms delay before disposing the stream.

**Here's my XAML code**

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding MyImageSource}" />
```

**Here's my C# code in ViewModel**

```cs
public ImageSource MyImageSource { get => myImageSource; set => SetProperty(ref myImageSource, value); }
ImageSource myImageSource;

public ICommand PickFiles => new Command(async () =>
{
    MediaPickResult results = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(5, MediaFileType.Image);
    IMediaFile[] selectedFiles = results?.Files?.ToArray();

    Stream stream = await selectedFiles[0].OpenReadAsync();
    MyImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

    // Everything is working fine until I add this line to dispose the stream. The Image is not shown
    stream.Close();

    // OR, this doesn't work too
    MyImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => 
    {
        Stream stream1 = stream;
        stream.Close();
        return stream1;
    });


    // It works as expected if I add a delay before disposing.
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.capsor.se/code/using-imagesource-fromstream-in-code-behind/).

Comment: When you load an Image from a Stream its only visible until your Stream is still available disposing of it basically removes it from memory.

Comment: @FreakyAli, but it does work when I add `await Task.Delay(3000);` before `stream.Close();`. The Image is shown properly even after disposing if I add a delay before disposing.